# AWS EC2 problem: mysql wont connect with sqlalchemy on my flask app

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, flask, sqlalchemy

I am a high school student trying to deploy a web api on EC2. I have been running into a problem where sqlalchemy (not flask_sqlalchemy) wont connect to mysql on ubuntu. I have typed in the password correctly, and am still getting:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
ubuntu@ip-172-31-3-251:~/deployedapp$
```

My code is:

```
engine=create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://*username*:*password*@localhost/*dbname*")
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you,

A confused high school coder.

EDIT:

This might have something to do with the problem. mysql -u root -p does not log me in. It says access denied. If I put sudo in front, it works.

Comment: The issue is only with sqlalchemy? In other words, can you connect using other means from the instnace, e.g. mysql cli?

Comment: Could I connect in a different way while still using sql alchemy?

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but for me to log into the database from the command line Ubuntu, I need to say sudo mysql -u etc. not just mysql -u etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to create a new user and grant al privileges on the database to them.